# Number of possible queries in a MySql DB

Tags: mysql

This is more of a theoretical question. Suppose we have a MySQL DB with n number of tables. Out of these m tables are possible to join (n-m tables cannot be joined on a key or won't even make any sense to join them). Given this; is there a finite number of MySQL queries possible for this DB and if so, how do we determine that number?

Comment: There will always be an infinite number of *queries* you can run against any database.  I assume you are wanting the number of possible combinations of data from each table?

Comment: What's a query?  I know it sound like a moronic statement, but how are you defining a variation of a query?  Is it the joins?  What happens if the FROM/JOIN/WHERE clauses are the same, but the SELECT changes (or the column order changes)?  What about the ORDER BY or the WHERE clause?

Comment: I have computed your answer: N = ∞

Comment: Can you elaborate on why you are asking this question?

Answer (score 0):

SQL is a constructive grammar and therefore has an limitless number of queries.

It doesn't matter how many tables are involved.